# $or operator in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB have priorities when using $or operator ? For instance , a query like that :

> `{$or : [ {id: {$in: arr_firstChild}},{id: {$in: arr_secondChild}}]}`

I checked and it returned the longer array(is arr_secondChild and it had more elements than that one). But it makes sense at all ? I can't find anything about it in MongoDB documentation.

Comment: You need to show a much clearer example. But there is no such thing as "ranking by number of matches" unless you specifically constructed an operation to do that. In fact unless you actually specify a `.sort()`, there is no "guaranteed" order at all.